# Size of beacons detected is not accurate

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, altbeacon

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

            Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);
            List<Beacon> beaconList = new ArrayList<Beacon>(beacons);

            if (beaconList.size() >= 2) {
                if (beaconList.get(0).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5A:34") && beaconList.get(1).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5B:AF")) {
                    if (beaconList.get(0).getDistance() < beaconList.get(1).getDistance()) {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "You're in room 1");
                    }
                }
                if (beaconList.get(1).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5A:34") && beaconList.get(0).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5B:AF")) {
                    if (beaconList.get(1).getDistance() < beaconList.get(0).getDistance()) {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "You're in room 1");
                    }
                }
                if (beaconList.get(0).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5B:AF") && beaconList.get(1).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5A:34")) {
                    if (beaconList.get(0).getDistance() < beaconList.get(1).getDistance()) {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "You're in room 2");
                    }
                }
                if (beaconList.get(1).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5B:AF") && beaconList.get(0).getBluetoothAddress().equals("20:91:48:4C:5A:34")) {
                    if (beaconList.get(1).getDistance() < beaconList.get(0).getDistance()) {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "You're in room 2");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "Less than 2 beacons detected");
            }
        }
    });
```

Whenever I run this code and have 2 ibeacons online, the `beaconList.size()` is supposed to be 2 but instead the size of the `beaconList` is 1 and the output that is printed in the log is

> 03-24 172233.292 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity You're in room 2
>   03-24 172234.412 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity You're in room 2
>   03-24 172235.552 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity You're in room 2
>   03-24 172236.737 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity Less than 2 beacons detected
>   03-24 172237.857 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity Less than 2 beacons detected
>   03-24 172239.012 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity Less than 2 beacons detected
>   03-24 172241.292 27699-27699net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth IMainActivity You're in room 2

The `beaconList.size()` is supposed to be of size 2 since I have 2 ibeacons online and I do have `Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);`
But instead somehow the size is 1 and keep printing less than 2 beacons and you're in room 2 instead. What seem to be the problem here?

Comment: something is not as you expect.  Are you certain two different beacons are advertising?  Are they each from a distinct hardware transmitter, or is it just one piece of hardware advertising two beacons?  Do they advertise at 1 Hz or more?   Try using an off the shelf beacon detector like BeaconScope to verify you see two beacons transmitting.

Comment: Yes they're two different beacons with different mac addresses, but they have same UUID that's why I'm using Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);

Comment: BeaconScope only detects one beacon though I have my 2 beacons online, probably because they have same identifiers, but even after adding Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true); still the list is of length 1.

Comment: While debugging, the beaconList.size() keeps changing from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1, I don't know why, that's why it keeps printing you're in room 2 then less than 2 beacons detected.

Comment: I think there is a delay between scanning each beacon, that's why each time didRangeBeaconsInRegion is called sometimes is scans 2 beacons and sometimes it scans only 1 beacon, how can I fix this issue? thanks.

Comment: If didRangeBeaconsInRegion the issue, is there any way I could let didRangeBeaconsInRegion wait like 10 seconds for scanning then enters into the if statements so it can take its time to scan all the beacons.

Comment: You can use `beaconManager.setScanPeriod(10000)` to make the library scan for 10 seconds (10000ms)  before each callback instead of the default 1100ms.

Comment: thank you so much, my code works perfectly now